# Magento attribute ( let model return value ? )

Tags: magento, attributes

I need a product attribute from which the value is returned by a model.

Attributes found in "`eav_attribute`" contain the following fields :

- attribute_model
- backend_model
- frontend_model
- source_model

How do I proceed? I'm already stuck.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: by default when we load a productattribute it gives us the value we entered in the backend. I need an attribute who returns me a value from php, not a database entry. So when i load $_product->getMyAttribute(); A model is returning the answer. Let's say the attribute sums up other product values.( price + shipping + rand(1,10))

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for a value that comes from a model, but here are some alternatives to get the same result.

**Option 1** - The observer approach.
Create an observer for the event `catalog_product_load_after` where your can calculate the value you need and store it to the product.

```
public function catalogProductLoadAfter($observer) {
    $product = $observe->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $myAttributeValue = $product->getPrice() + rand(1, 10);
    $product->setMyAttribute($myAttributeValue);
}
```

Then you will be able to call `$product->getMyAttribute()` and you will get the correct result.

**Option 2** - rewrite.
Rewrite the product model and add a method called `getMyAttribute` that contains the logic of your attribute value.